# how to delete textboxes dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net

cs code

```
 protected void DeleteNewRowToGrid()
    {
        int rowIndex = 0; 
        if (ViewState["dtCurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable DeldtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["dtCurrentTable"];
            DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
            if (DeldtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i > DeldtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i--)
                {
                    //extract the TextBox values
                    TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");
                    //TextBox box2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");
                    DropDownList box2 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("ddldatatype");

                    drCurrentRow = DeldtCurrentTable.NewRow();
                    drCurrentRow["RowNumber"] = i - 1;
                    drCurrentRow["Column1"] = box1.Text;
                    drCurrentRow["Column2"] = box2.Text;
                    //drCurrentRow["Column3"] = box3.Text;

                    rowIndex--;
                }
                //add new row to DataTable
                DeldtCurrentTable.Rows.Remove(drCurrentRow);
                //Store the current data to ViewState
                ViewState["dtCurrentTable"] = DeldtCurrentTable;

                //Rebind the Grid with the current data
                Gridview1.DataSource = DeldtCurrentTable;
                Gridview1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void ButtonDel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DeleteNewRowToGrid();
    }
aspx code

 <asp:gridview ID="Gridview1" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="Row Number" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Column Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
     <%-- <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 2">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>--%>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Data Type">
            <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddldatatype" runat="server">
                  <asp:ListItem>varchar</asp:ListItem>
                  <asp:ListItem>int</asp:ListItem>
                  <asp:ListItem>numeric</asp:ListItem>
                  <asp:ListItem>uniqueidentifier</asp:ListItem>
                  <asp:ListItem>char</asp:ListItem>
                  </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" Text="Add New Row" OnClick="ButtonAdd_Click"/>
             <asp:Button ID="ButtonDel" runat="server" Text="Delete Row" OnClick="ButtonDel_Click"/>
             <input type="hidden" runat="server" value="0" id="hiddencount" />
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
</asp:gridview>

I have done with add rwo, now I want to delete
```

Comment: i tried code for delete what i iven

Comment: Are you removing fist row on every button click ,Dats what it suggests from code

Comment: you can only find grid rows for first iteration of i ; for the second iteration of i , rowIndex = -1 . which will result in Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex] a  null value

Comment: I am adding textbox on click Add Row.. I want to delete row now onclick Delete Row

Comment: I dont understand why that loop is for ?

Comment: Your question says TextBox, but your code says DataRow. Which are you trying to delete?

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to deleta a row "drCurrentRow" that's not even in your DataTable, because you created this `drCurrentRow = DeldtCurrentTable.NewRow();` yourself and didn't even insert it (no use anyway).

You have to search the rows to delete from your source like this:

```
var toDel = DeldtCurrentTable.Where(row => /* true if found */).ToArray();
foreach(var t in toDel) DeldtCurrentTable.Rows.Remove(t);
```

and then you can reiterate and set your rownumbers again.

Finaly set the the ViewState and the DataSource + DataBind it

BTW: your naming is really frustrating - what the heck does "DeleteNewRowToGrid" mean? Do you want to delete some new row? *What* is the a new row in this case?
So: Which row should be deleted here?

Comment: Ia m adding textboxes dynamically onclick Add row.. now i want to delete it also now

Comment: yes Ithink I can remember - and as you added them to the table/dataset you need to remove them from there - so you have to find a row *in* the set/table and call .Rows.Remove on this. You called remove on a *new* row that is not attached to the table/set at all!

Comment: I gave the code in my answer - you have to find the row(s) to delete with .Where or .FirstOrDefault, or something (you can even iterate through them and check yourself or youse LINQs from ... where ... syntax) and then delete it - I cannot give you a code-snippet from your code because I don't see what row your are trying to delete there (some row with Id=????, some other predicate?)

Comment: see - I try but what shall I do - you don't answer my questions and I cannot work with the code I see because I don't understand "which row" you want to delete! ...

Comment: I have sent u my code there is application in which I m adding rows onclick Add Rows. as "Row no, "Column name,  Data type"" for these i m  creating textboxes dynamically for column name. when i m adding rows, that are adding. but if user want to delete rows then he sholud get option like delete row. so im giving button that is Delete row on which click he able to delete row.. i am trying to make an application such as we can create table from aspx and cs page.. no need to write insert statements, etc I hope u understand what i want.. so plz help me.. if u want then I can send my code again

Comment: so you want to see a "Delete"-Button in each row of your GridView? Normaly you do this by using a Command(Button?)Column in your GridView and handling the Command-Events. Alternative you can let the user select a Row and have a delete-button that deletes the selected line. In the first case you bind some id to your command to identify the row to delete in the second case you search for the selected-row and extract the id from there. in both cases you can use the code given here to delete the row from the source. For the other things please make a new question - and please set this to answered